# Can't run vba function

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to run this function to count the number of rows in each sheet in the current workbook. I got the function from a previously answered question.

However, when I try to run it, it asks me to create a macro, when I do it creates a "Sub ()", when I place the functions inside it, it gives me the error of "Expected End Sub" I'm not sure what to do. I've tried various ways of re-writing the code but to no avail.

I am new to vba and am not sure what is wrong here.

```
Function Test_It()
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Debug.Print Sheet.Name & vbTab & CountMyRows(Sheet.Name)
    Next Sheet
End Function


Function CountMyRows(SName) As Long         '# where SName is the name of a sheet
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    CountMyRows = rowCount
End Function
```

Comment: Test_it is a sub not a function because it does not return a value. Try reading up on the difference between defining a function and a sub in VBA.  Perhaps you should work your way through a VBA tutorial.  You also need to tell us how you are trying to run your macro.

Comment: Also why do you need a small separate function for this? Simply change `Debug.Print Sheet.Name & vbTab & CountMyRows(Sheet.Name)` to `Debug.Print Sheet.Name & vbTab & Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using a `Function` in a `Sub`

- Note that the `Sheets` collection (of the `Workbook` object) also includes charts that do not have a `UsedRange`.
- When writing a function that refers to an object, it is best to use the object as an argument. For example, in your version of the function you are using the unqualified `Worksheets(SName)` where we don't know to which workbook it belongs. So if `ThisWorkbook` in the `Sub` is not active, the function may fail or may fail to write the right result.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test_It()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name & vbTab & CountMyRows(ws)
        ' Without the function (the function is kind of useless):
        'Debug.Print ws.Name & vbTab & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Next ws
End Sub

Function CountMyRows(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Long
    If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    CountMyRows = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Function
```

### EDIT

**A More Practical Example**

The following will write the worksheet names and the corresponding 'used range rows counts' of `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook containing this code) to the first worksheet of a new workbook.

```
Sub testRowsCount()
    
    ' Add a new (destination) workbook and create a reference
    ' to its first (destination) worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1)
    
    ' Write headers.
    dws.Cells(1, "A").Value = "Name"
    dws.Cells(1, "B").Value = "RowsCount"
    ' Define destination rows counter.
    Dim n As Long: n = 1
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    
    ' Loop through the worksheets collection (all worksheets)
    ' of the Source Workbook and write the names and used range
    ' rows counts to the Destination Worksheet.
    For Each sws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        n = n + 1
        dws.Cells(n, "A").Value = sws.Name
        dws.Cells(n, "B").Value = CountMyRows(sws)
    Next sws

    dws.Parent.Saved = True ' for easy closing only.

End Sub
```

Comment: nicely explained

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand the logic a little better no, but it is still not working. The function doesn't run. Either on a specific sheet or on another empty sheet. Shouldn't it count the number of rows in each sheet and write them on the final sheet?
Like
28
70
82
.
.
.
etc?

Comment: No. At the moment, when you run the `Sub`, it is writing the results to the `VBE's` (`Alt+F11`) `Immediate window` (`Ctrl+G`). You haven't specified any range (first cell to write to), worksheet, or workbook to write the result to. Elaborate on it (final sheet?, where?), and I'll add a suitable solution.

Comment: I would like it to write it in the final sheet, and start at A1 down to A XX. Thank, you.

Comment: Thank you very much VBasic, you've been a great help. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

The `Test_It` doesnt give back a value, therefore it should be a sub. Read the articles [Function statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement) and [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) to understand the difference.

```
Sub Test_It()
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Debug.Print Sheet.Name & vbTab & CountMyRows(Sheet.Name)
    Next Sheet
End Function   

Function CountMyRows(SName) As Long         '# where SName is the name of a sheet
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    CountMyRows = rowCount
End Function
```

That will do the job. If you want to get the count into a cell in your workbook, you could take this:

```
Function Test_It()
    Test_It = CountMyRows(ActiveSheet.Name)
End Function       
    
Function CountMyRows(SName) As Long         '# where SName is the name of a sheet
    Dim rowCount As Long
    CountMyRows = Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Function
```

Just put `=Test_It()` into a cell and you´ll get the count.

Comment: When trying to use the 2nd code, it prompts me to save the macro, and opens a "Sub()" which is my initial problem in the first place.

Comment: I corrected it, its not Activeworksheet but ActiveSheet, only problem with that is if you dont have a worksheet active but a graph but if you use it like a normal function it should work all the time because to write it in a cell you need to have a worksheets active accept for the case that you put it in with an vba sub.

Comment: it still prompts me to save it as a macro, which creates a "Sub()" unless you meant for the Test_It to be a sub()

Comment: It shows you that when you call it in a cell with =Test_It() ?

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I attempted to run it wrong.

Comment: Ah great. The Answer from VBasic2008 is way more explained, so please approve it.